# Why does SQL Server override my scale value when I am casting from VARCHAR(MAX) to Numeric(P,S)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes

I am trying to understand why SQL Server is modifying my scale value when I cast a value from `VARCHAR(MAX)` to `NUMERIC(P,S)`.

Here is the example:

```
--declare @val1 as numeric (18,6)
--declare @val2 as numeric (18,6)

DECLARE @val1 AS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @val2 AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @val1 = '2383.4912500000'
SET @val2 = '2383.4912000000'

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TMP

SELECT
    V1 = @VAL1, 
    VC1 = CAST(@VAL1 AS NUMERIC(30, 20)),
    valDiff = ABS(CAST(CAST(@VAL2 AS NUMERIC(18, 6)) - CAST(@VAL1 AS NUMERIC(18, 6)) AS NUMERIC(30, 20)) / @VAL1) 
INTO  
    TMP

SELECT * FROM TMP

-- when variable is VARCHAR(MAX), valDiff == 0.00000002 which is correct, but rounded.

-- when the variable is NUMERIC(18, 6), valDiff == 0.0000000209776310275945 which is correct and not rounded
```

Comment: Have you considered... not storing a number in `varchar(max)`?

Comment: Yes. This is not my codebase. The team who owns this code are less savvy with their SQL ability. I am mostly interested in understanding why SQL Server does this.

Comment: the datatype of valDiff is decimal(38,8)..  0.00000002      :: 8 decimal points

Comment: @lptr I am aware of the data type that SQL creates. the question is why does it set as 38,8? I have my variables casting to 30,20?

Comment: @mdiprima .. yes, the denominator @val1[varchar] is cast() implicitly to the numeric datatype of the numerator.. the first is (30,20)/(30,20) —> (38,8) the second (18,6)/(18,6)—>(38,20)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start with decimals with very high precision, the results of arithmetic operations may have their scale reduced to preserve more significant digits.  It doesn't matter if the values *dont have* 30 non-zero digits to the left of the decimal point.  The conversions are based on the declared precision and scale:

[image]

[Precision and Scale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

And here your `varchar` is going through an implicit conversion to a decimal with excessive precision.

Because of the need to carefully cast intermediate results with decimal, it's often easier to perform all the calculations using `float`, which maintains ~15 significant digits of precision across all scales, and only cast the final result to `decimal` for storage. eg

```
declare @val1 as float ='2383.4912500000'
declare @val2 as float ='2383.4912000000'

select cast( abs(@VAL2 - @VAL1) / @VAL1 as numeric(30,20) )
```

Comment: Yes I see now. I was trying earlier to understand the matrix, and I did not see the extra conditions below for multiplication and division. After properly including those conditions in my work, I am now able to see the values in my work. Thank you for sharing, and thank you for the float recommendation!